# Dictionary with custom extensions or ConcurrentDictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I wrote a method that collected errors through the process (instead of failing on the first error). This is more for validation. It worked something like this.

```
var errors = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
// Do some work, and if error
errors.AddOrUpdate(nameof(object.Property), "Specific error message.");
```

And this used the custom extension I wrote for Dictionary.

```
public static void AddOrUpdate(this Dictionary<string, string[]> dictionary, string key, string value)
{
    dictionary.AddOrUpdate(key, new [] { value });
}

public static void AddOrUpdate(this Dictionary<string, string[]> dictionary, string key, string[] values)
{
    if (dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        dictionary[key] = dictionary[key].Concat(values).ToArray();
    }
    else
    {
        dictionary.Add(key, values);
    }
}
```

During review, my co-worker suggested using `ConcurrentDictionary`. To which I came up with this:

```
var errors = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string[]>();
// Do some work, and if error
var errorMessage = $"{input.PurchaseOrder} - Purchase Orders require a contact email address.";
errors.AddOrUpdate(nameof(input.ContactEmail),
    new[] { errorMessage }, 
    (k,oldValue) => ConcurrentDictionaryHelper.AddStringToArray(oldValue, errorMessage));
```

With the helper method:

```
public static string[] AddStringToArray(string[] values, string newValue)
{
    var valuesList = values.ToList();
    valuesList.Add(newValue);
    return valuesList.ToArray();
}
```

While I see the power in `ConcurrentDictionary` allowing the functions, I'm having a hard time seeing how it is an improvement in this case. I felt my implementation was more intuitive.

Am I missing something? Or is this more a matter of preference in this case?

Comment: `ConcurrentDictionary` is thread-safe, do you have a multi threaded application?

Comment: You are not missing anything.  There was clamor in the [github.com issues](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/14676) to improve Dictionary<>.  ConcurrentDictionary *must* have such a method to ensure thread-safety.  But it is not for free, the interlocking is expensive.  So no, this is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

`ConcurrentDictionary` is useful if you're running operations add/remove from differents threads. If your validation runs in a single thread, then you can keep the `Dictionary<string, string[]>`.

**A recomendation:** change the dictionary type to `Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>` this way you will avoid duplicated errors(if any) and it will have a much better performance (currently you're concatenating string arrays).

Here is an extension:

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static void AddValidationError(
        this IDictionary<string, HashSet<string>> dictionary,
        [NotNull] string property,
        [NotNull] string error)
    {
        if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(property, out var errors))
            errors = new HashSet<string>();

        errors.Add(error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

ConcurrentDictionary is thread safe, so you won't get exceptions when multiple threads will attempt to write to the same Dictionary at the same time.
You could use a Dictionary of lists, this way you won't need to convert from array to list and back.
Here is a generic implementation:

```
    public static TList AddToList<TKey, TValue, TList>(this IDictionary<TKey, TList> target, TKey key, params TValue[] values)
        where TList : ICollection<TValue>, new()
    {
        TList theReturn;
        lock (target)
        {
            if (!target.TryGetValue(key, out theReturn))
            {
                theReturn = new TList();
                target.Add(key, theReturn);
            }
        }
        lock (theReturn)
        {
            foreach (var currentValue in values)
            {
                theReturn.Add(currentValue);
            }
        }
        return theReturn;
    }
```